# Creating an instance of a class without defining the __init__ function

Tags: python, class, init

I am relativly new to python and I was wondering if you could create an instance of a class without defining the **init** explicity. Could I call it something else?

First example - with the **init** method:

```
class dog:
def __init__(self,name):
    self.name=name
    print('My name is',name)
Bob = dog('Bob')
```

Second example - without the **init** method:

```
class dog:
def init_instance(self,name):
    self.name = name
    print('My name is',name)

Bob = dog('Bob')
```

In the first example the code works but in the second example I get:

> TypeError: object() takes no parameters

So based on this I assume that one has to **explicitly** call the **init** method. BUT I have seen code where the **init** method has not been used, how come?

Comment: Check out `__new__()`

Comment: When creating an object from class the parameters you pass are passed to the `__init__` function declared in the class. Since you have not declared it, python will fall back to the default implementation which does not accept any arguments. `Bob = dog()` and then `Bob.init_instance("Bob")` will work.

Comment: Well, Python isn’t going to know that it should call something named `init_instance` instead of `__init__`, but you can make `init_instance` a [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) and call `dog.init_instance('Bob')` (changing it to also create an instance instead of just initializing one).

Comment: Maybe if you said why you are trying to do this, you would get better help.

Comment: @Ryan This was what I was confused about. In every example and explanation that I have read they say that when creating a object of a class the __init__() initalize the object. So I assumed that as soon as I have created an instance the __init__() is automatically called.

Comment: @Anake I am not trying to do anything, just trying to understand why I explicity need to call __init__(). Why I cant name it someting else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every class has an `__init__` method. If it doesn't explicitly define one, then it will inherit one from its parent class. In your 2nd example, the class inherits `__init__` and a bunch of other methods (and other non-method attributes) from the base `object` class. We can see that via the `dir` function:

```
class Dog:
    def init_instance(self,name):
        self.name = name
        print('My name is',name)

print(dir(Dog))
```

**output**

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'init_instance']
```

`__init__` gets called automatically after the instance is constructed (via the `__new__` method), so we might as well use it if we need to initialize our instance. But we can call your `init_instance` explicitly:

```
bob = Dog()
bob.init_instance('Bob')
print(bob.name)
```

**output**

```
My name is Bob
Bob
```

If you give you class an initializer that isn't named `__init__` then it *won't* get called automatically. How should Python know that that method is an initializer? Although it's customary to make `__init__` the first method in the class definition, that's by no means mandatory, and some people like to put `__init__` *last*.

You said: "I have seen code where the init method has not been used, how come?" Well, some classes simply don't need their instances to be initialized: their instance attributes are set via various other methods, or by direct assignment in code outside the class definition, eg `bob.color = 'brown'`. Or they inherit a perfectly usable `__init__` from a parent class.

Comment: This was a good explanation, finally. So I want to summarize how it works when creating an object: 

__new__() creates the instance

__init__() initalize the instance, i.e. preparing my object to have e.g. names, colors etc. 

But we can make our own initializer and call it instead.

Comment: @John Correct. In fact, with large classes (eg for a GUI), it's common to break up the initialization into separate logical stages, with a separate method for each stage, and have `__init__` call those methods.

Answer (score 1):

`init` is nothing else then a method to initially prepare the state of your object. In other languages they have similar concepts as `Constructors` and it's not necessarily needed.

Comment: Sometimes `__init__` is called the constructor, but technically speaking, that's not correct. The constructor in Python is `__new__`, and `__init__` is the initializer.

Comment: Technically both are used to construct objects, but talking about priorities, `__new__` is the one that is first called.

Comment: Well sure, because `__init__` (usually) constructs the instance attributes. OTOH, a lot of terminology used to describe the mechanics of other languages doesn't really apply well to Python because Python doesn't have declarations, it just defines things.

Comment: That's true, I just thought if the OP is coming from a different programming background `Constructor` might be the most close thing to understand of what init does.